# Why is padding right clipped with overflow:scroll

Tags: html, css

In the snippet below, `padding-right` for `.ctr` is not visible when content starts to overflow at small viewports.

**I've read other answers and I know how to fix it**.
I just need to move `padding:20px` from `.ctr` to `.row`. Or just add `margin-right:20px` to last child.

**But, I couldn't find the reason as to why this happens**. Could someone please explain, what's going on? any resource for further learning will be highly appreciated

Thanks!

```css
.ctr {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.child:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctr">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The padding is actually there when the content overflow it hides it.

we can illustrate this using `background` and `background-origin`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, red) no-repeat;
  background-origin: content-box;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.overflow {
  background: pink;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overflow"></div>
</div>
the white space you see on the edges is the padding
```

`background-origin: content-box;` makes the background exclude border and padding which will show us that the padding isn't clipped only covered, this happens because padding is part of the parent and the content overflow the parent so it covers it.

There's nothing special about this.

Answer (score 1):

Dude the reason is the `rendering or calculation` in browsers (or the logic or system that we have developed starts from the `top/left` and ends at `right/bottom`). So, padding the hierarchy of placement is:

`margin > border > padding > content`

(And, remember it starts with top/left).

Now the issue you are seeing is only because you have not increased the height of item. If you do so - You will not only find issue on the `right-padding` but also on the `bottom-padding`.

`Padding` is only an effort to wrap something which is flexible. When you give a 600 * 5 width to items then they take more width than available.

`padding` is not as strong contender like margin. Because, margin you `apply` on same element - whose width or height you are manipulating. `padding` is being applied on an element which is trying to *impose* restrictions on **some other element** (usually direct child). So, this is the difference between `padding` and `margin` and how they get applied on `browsers` via `Box-Model`.

Hope, this clarifies a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, not exactly the same but very close to this.
Adding : `min-width: max-content;` to the parent component made right paddings and margins show. (I kind of know why... It has to do with the width of the parent component in comparison to the width of the body when there's a visible overflow. But I don't know how to explain it because my english isn't the best. I wish they had a better default behaviour than cutting only right margins/paddings)

Comment: Could you explain more about your answer by providing a working example?